# how to get the values in json array in mvc3 controller?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a result that contains Json result. The Json Result are as follows.

```
      <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        {"Method":"LOGIN_AUTHENTICATE Start :8/29/2013 1:23:46 AM 
          ASW :8/29/2013 1:23:46 AM P21 :8/29/2013 1:23:50 AM End :8/29/2013 1:23:50AM",
        "ResponseCode":0,"ResponseText":"","HomeBannerURL":"http://example.com/example/",
        "resAccount":[{"shopper_uid":1877,"customer_code":"10950",
         "customer_name":"JASPER ACCOUNT",
         "contact_id":6449,"first_name":"jasper","last_name":"manickaraj",
         "email_address":"exam@example.com","password_hint":"name",
         "default_shipping_method_uid":110,"password":"abc123",
         "default_ship_to_address_id":"150"}],
         "resCategories":
 [{"item_category_uid":123,
        "item_category_desc":"EFG",
        "Total":0,"sub_category_image":"",
        "sub_category_thumb":""},
 {"item_category_uid":1,
        "item_category_desc":"ABC",
        "Total":0,"sub_category_image":"",
        "sub_category_thumb":""},
 {"item_category_uid":2,
        "item_category_desc":"BCD",
        "Total":0,"sub_category_image":"",
        "sub_category_thumb":""},
 {"item_category_uid":3,
        "item_category_desc":"CDE",
        "Total":0,"sub_category_image":"",
        "sub_category_thumb":""}]}
    <string>
```

Now i assign the above result to var Jsonresult;
Now i need to get the customer_name, first_name from Jsonresult.. 
How to get the result..
Please help me to fix this..

Comment: `Jsonresult.customer_name` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScriptSerializer to implement this feature.
First,you must define a few entity,eg.

```
public class RequestObj
{
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string HomeBannerURL { get; set; }

    public IList<Account> ResAccount { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{

    public string shopper_uid { get; set; }

    public string customer_name { get; set; }

    public string first_name { get; set; }
}
```

second,you can deserialize your string.

```
var scriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var obj = scriptSerializer.Deserialize<RequestObj>(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok,you must add json.net dll in your project,and you such so write code:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(str.ToString());
```

Comment: json.net dll is not available